# C++: initializing 2 objects -> output not as expected

Tags: c++

My Programs creates two objects (a1 and a2) and initializes a1 with the value 42 and a2 with the value 11. The constructor sets variables num and x to exactly this value.

But my program output is this (not as expected 42 42):

```
11
42
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
        static int num;
        int x;
        public:
        A(int n) {
                num = n;
                x = n;
        }

        void print() {
                cout << num << endl;
                cout << x << endl;
                cout << endl;
        }
};

int A::num;

int main() {
        A a1(42);
        A a2(11);
        a1.print();
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint why, num from object a1 gets "overwritten" when i create object a2? Thanks so many...

Comment: do you know what the `static` keyword means ?

Comment: That's what `static` does.

Comment: Why do people downvote the question? Sure, it's a beginners mistake, but the question is perfectly fine?

Comment: The only questions that get upvoted are the obscure ones. StackOverflow 101.

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson [Meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/is-it-reasonable-to-downvote-a-question-that-could-be-googled-but-isnt-a-dupl)

Comment: @Simple yes, working as intended. The purpose of this site is to build a knowledge base; questions that contribute new content get upvoted, and questions that duplicate existing content and/or lack minimal research effort get downvoted.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Sure, downvote questions that are easily googled. Allthough if you are a complete beginner to c++, it might not be obvious that ´static´ is the thing to google.. I dont think this is a "just google it"-question

Answer (score 1):

Because "num" is a static variable, meaning it's a class variable: there's only one value for all instances.

Answer (score 1):

Static class member is shared between all instances of a class. So when you create `A a2(11)`, num is overwritten to 11.

This is normal static behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine. `num` is a static variable, meaning it is shared among all the instances of a class. When you assign `num` in `a2`'s constructor, you assign `num` for **all** the instances.

Answer (score 0):

You have the static keyword. The static keyword is shared amongst all of the objects, meaning that a1, a2 and all other objects of type A will have the same `num`

If you remove the static so that it looks like this:

```
int num;
int x;
```

it should output

```
42
42
```